# Can you detect/redirect a back button press through javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to detect and change browser behavior if a user clicks on the back button.

Is this even possible through Javascript?

Comment: http://www.irt.org/script/311.htm

Comment: You can mess with my back button when you pry it from my cold, dead hands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow i just learnt a lot by reading this tutorial on javascript. 
It talks about the following things:

**Mastering The Back Button With Javascript**

- window.onbeforeunload
- Are you really, really sure you want to leave my glorious page?
- Detecting When The User Has Clicked Cancel
- Truly Dynamic Pages
- Some security considerations.
- You can't change history, and lastly
- If you MUST control History

which talks about how history have been made with lock down. You can make limited changes. But you can put a replacement URL so if a person does decided to go back it will redirect it to a different page. It will be good for security reasons, if a person logs in then logs out, and another person presses the back button, the page will just be taken to the replacement page.

check it out
Its really short and precise, informative article/tutorial and contains many java snippets to help you for each section.

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript

I hope this helps.

**PK**

Answer (score 1):

I've just asked the same question, which got closed since it is a duplicate of yours. Here's the essense of my solution:

Form fields are automatically fetched from the browser's cache, thus holding historic data. while this is true, javascript code is run independently each time.

So I created a small hidden field to hold a timestamp and compare it against the javascript's generated datatime.

Here is the code, I am sure it can be much better implemented, though time is short:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var date = new Date();
     var clientMiliseconds = date.getTime();
     clientMiliseconds = roundTime(clientMiliseconds);
     var serverTimeStamp = $('#' + '<%= hfTimeStamp.ClientID %>').val();
     serverTimeStamp = roundTime(serverTimeStamp);
     alert(serverTimeStamp == clientMiliseconds);
});


function roundTime(time) {
    time = Math.floor(time);
     //since the server renders the time components a few seconds before the page is downloaded 
     //which also depends on where you assign the date on the serverside 
     //we've got a small inaccuracy of few seconds. we neglect these seconds, assuming that it would take the user
     //a few seconds to click the back button

     time = time / 10000;
     time = Math.floor(time);
     return time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be only possible  to implement a link to "Back" within your html page and then add your JS function there. However, it is not possible to detect what user is doing with the browser (like clicking the browser Back button) in JS because it happens outside of the context of the page loaded, and there is no standard specification to feed the web server with data from browser GUI. You could attempt to develop a custom plugin for this to run on browser and feed the www server with data on this, but again, this is a non-standard solution, and not all users would install some 3rd party plugin very easily.

Hope this helps.